# ListView scrollbarStyle not working properly in a Widget

Tags: android, listview, android-widget, android-scrollbar

I'm trying to do a Widget with a ListView, but I want to show the ScrollBar really in the right side, without any padding.

I want it like the gmail calendar Widget. I will show you how with pictures:
[image]

This is my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/widgetTitle"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="@drawable/widget_title_background"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/widget_title_min_height"></TextView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/widgetListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"    
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
            tools:listitem="@layout/widget_list_item"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when you give listview control height and width match_parent then textview not show.

Comment: If you show only listview then used below code.

Answer (score 0):

In Listview control scrollbar default show on right side always.
Try This code ..

```
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listview"></ListView>
```

Comment: Yep, on right side, but with a little padding between the scrollbar and the border of the widget. I will edit the post.